# Decrypt AES encrypted file in java

Tags: java, key, aes, encryption

I have a file encrypted with java application using AES. I also have a key file was encrypted with. But i can't understand how to use the key to decrypt file. Most tutorials and examples create temporary random key, encrypt file and decrypt it in one place.
So, question is **how to specify a key which have to be used for decryption?**

**EDIT**: 
Samples i found use following code to generate key. I have no idea where i can use my key here.

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128);
SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
```

Comment: Can't you just drop your key into the tutorial in place of the random key? Or do you actually need to convert a password and salt into the key bits? If you point us as the same tutorial you're looking at (and / or quote a bit of the code here) we might be able to help figure out how to change it.

Comment: @Rup I think it is just a small conversion problem where the bytes need to be turned into a Java Key instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarise my comments to Lucifer's answer.

1. If you don't know what padding was used to encrypt, then decrypt with 'no padding' set.  That will decrypt everything, including the padding, and won't throw an error because of mismatched padding.
2. When you have decrypted the cyphertext, have a look at the last block of the output and see what padding was used.  Different paddings leave different byte patterns, so it is usually easy enough to tell.
3. Set your decryption method to expect the correct type of padding, and it will be automatically removed for you.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Turned out decryption result was GZIP-ed. Now i have expected result. Thanks again!

Comment: For unix adepts, it never hurts to run the "file" command against output you cannot figure out...

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be simply to put the key data as bytes into a SecretKeySpec like this:

```
SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(myKeyData, "AES");
```

Note that [SecretKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html) implements the Key interface, so you can use it directly in a `Cipher.init()` method. So there is no SecretKeyFactory needed, which you would use otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I decrypted file, but it's content is binary mess. It's obvious that i did something wrong.

Comment: Is the entire message a mess, or just the first 16 bytes? Can you give us a bit more information on the algorithm used, and if you have specified an IV vector (if the mode = CBC)? What kind of padding? These you specify in `Cipher.getInstance(<algorithm[opt: /mode][opt: /padding]>);`

Comment: Whole file is a mess. Here's the story: the file i want to decrypt is .script file from HSQLDB database. Normally it's a plain text file containing log of changes. But some guy decided to use database encryption like described at [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/515884/JDBC/java/Encrypted-database-HSQL). Somehow database got corrupted and client wants to restore data. So i don't know any encryption options hsqldb used to encrypt. Parameters given to DB engine are "AES" and 128-bit key.Nothing else.

Comment: It says that the database supports any algorithm, so it might well be that it just uses `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` , which is the same (when using Sun Java) as `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");`. It might however well be that only specific parts are encrypted, you must make sure that you only decrypt those parts.

Comment: No luck so far. Specified options above. Still can't decrypt.

Comment: Have you tried AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding? It could be that the first block does not decrypt. In that case you are either missing the IV or it *is* the IV…

Comment: I tried AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding with IV from sample code{0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04...}.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following methods, if might helpful for you.

```
private static byte[] cipherData(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher, byte[] data)
        throws Exception
{
    int minSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
    byte[] outBuf = new byte[minSize];
    int length1 = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, outBuf, 0);
    int length2 = cipher.doFinal(outBuf, length1);
    int actualLength = length1 + length2;
    byte[] result = new byte[actualLength];
    System.arraycopy(outBuf, 0, result, 0, result.length);
    return result;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipher, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception
{
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aes = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(
            new AESEngine()));
    CipherParameters ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
    aes.init(false, ivAndKey);
    return cipherData(aes, cipher);
}

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plain, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception
{
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aes = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(
            new AESEngine()));
    CipherParameters ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
    aes.init(true, ivAndKey);
    return cipherData(aes, plain);
}
```

Comment: I've got "org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted".

Comment: Check that you specify the same padding for decryption as for encryption.  If you don't know, then specify 'no padding' for decryption, and look at the end of the last block to determine what padding was being used to encrypt.

Comment: @rossum: if i only knew the padding they used for encryption.

Comment: @Aleksandr Kravets: Decrypt with 'no padding' explicitly set and check the end of the last block.  That will show what padding, if any, was added before encryption.  Setting 'no padding' will accept whatever is in the last block as valid.

Comment: @rossum: decrypted with no padding. last block contains 7 bytes of value 0x07. Any further directions =) ?

Comment: @Aleksandr Kravets: Seven bytes of 0x07 means you have PKCS5/PKCS7 padding on the incoming cyphertext.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography) for an explanation.  Set your decryption method to expect the same padding and it will automatically be removed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Complete example of *encrypting/Decrypting* a **huge video without throwing Java** `OutOfMemoryException` and using Java `SecureRandom` for Initialization Vector generation. Also depicted storing key bytes to database and then reconstructing same key from those bytes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18892960/185022