# Decrypting does not happen correctly

Tags: java, encryption

I import an XML file as a byte array to the project

```
RandomAccessFile rnd = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) rnd.length()];
rnd.read(fileData);
```

I encrypted the array using java.crypto

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

byte[] encypted = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(fileData.length)];
int len = cipher.update(fileData, 0, fileData.length, encypted, 0);
len += cipher.doFinal(encypted, len);
```

When I decrypt the byte array and print it using

```
System.out.println(new String(decrypted, "UTF-8"));
```

I got the XML file but there were some unkown characters at the end (they are only at the end). Is there any way I can remove this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000999/decrypt-aes-encrypted-file-in-java), the answer though is what might be very relavent to your situation:

> 1.If you don't know what padding was used to encrypt, then decrypt with
>     'no padding' set. That will decrypt everything, including the padding,
>     and won't throw an error because of mismatched padding.
>
> 2.When you have decrypted the cyphertext, have a look at the last block
>     of the output and see what padding was used. Different paddings leave
>     different byte patterns, so it is usually easy enough to tell.
>
> 3.Set your decryption method to expect the correct type of padding, and
>     it will be automatically removed for you.

and incase this is relavant to you here is a link on padding patterns etc: [Padding Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29.)

This over here is also a very good tutorial for encrypting using DES: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/desstring.html and here is for PBE in DES: 
[PBE with HMAC(SHA1) and DES(EDE)](http://www.rsa.com/products/bsafe/documentation/cryptoj35html/doc/dev_guide/group__CJ__SAMPLES__PBEH.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of missing code that might be important. One thing that I note is that you are reading the data in without any character encoding specified, then upon decryption your are creating a string using a UTF-8 decoder. That only makes sense if the original XML file was UTF-8 encoded, which is entirely possible. Also, `RandomAccessFile.read()` returns an int containing the number of bytes actually read. You're supposed to use that number rather than assuming that the entire array is read in.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the padding and it worked.

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CFB8/NoPadding");
```