# Encrypt and decrypt doesn't give the same plain text using AES/ECB/NoPadding

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rijndael

```
String plain1= "Test";
byte[] cipher = SplashSecure.getInstance().encrypt2(plain1);
String plain2 = SplashSecure.getInstance().decrypt2(cipher);
```

> plain = Test������������������������

After decryption `plainText2` should be equal to `plaintext`. But it's not.

Encrypt/Decrypt methods.

```
 public void initKey(String key) {
    String paddedKey = Utils.padString(key);
    mKeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(Utils.getBytes(paddedKey), "AES/ECB/NoPadding");
                   // Utils.getBytes returns "paddedKey.getBytes("CP1252")"
 }

public byte[] encrypt2(String data) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mKeyspec);
        String paddedData = Utils.padString(data);
        return cipher.doFinal(Utils.getBytes(paddedData));

    } catch(InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    // Series of catch blocks
    }
    return null;
}

public String decrypt2(byte[] cypherText) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mKeyspec);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(cypherText);
        return Utils.getString(plainTextBytes);
        // Utils.getString returns "new String(bytes, "CP1252");"
    } catch(InvalidKeyException e) {
        // Series of catch blocks.
    } 
    return null;
}
```

### Edit

```
public static String padString(String source) {
    char paddingChar = '\0';
    int size = 16;
    int padLength = size - source.length() % size;

    for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++) {
        source += paddingChar;
    }

    return source;
}
```

### Edit

I'm trying to get the encryption-decryption working across Windows (other client that encrypts, and server) and Android. The Windows client is a VC++ app that uses a Rijndael class (http://svn.openfoundry.org/pcman/2007.06.03/Lite/Rijndael.h) and Android uses http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/ocb-java/Rijndael.java. The Windows client has encrypted the data and stored it on the server. I need to build a client for android that fetches the encrypted data, decrypt it and display to the user.

I'm sure I'm using the correct key to decrypt.

Comment: It will be useful to post `Utils.padString()` code as well

Comment: What is `plainText2`?

Comment: Its for testing the encryption.. I check the plaintext2 equals plaintext. to make sure that encryption is working correctly..

Comment: *What* Rijndael java implementation would that be?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to duplicate the PHP mcrypt library. That library really does too many things wrong, it would be much better to use PHP in such a manner that it does comply to the usual standards (specifying a character encoding, (only) using an IV in CBC mode, using PKCS#7 padding, a secure random generator, not expanding keys and IV's with zero's and whatnot).

Comment: The line `String cipher = new String(encrypt(plainText));` usually does not make sense and will destroy the ciphertext making decryption impossible. A String can be constructed by decoding a sequence of bytes together with a decoding standard like UTF-8, but not every sequence of bytes can be decoded. ciphertext may be any sequence of bytes, therefore your scheme can't work.

Comment: @owlstead I picked the impleemtnation form here : http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/ocb-java/Rijndael.java

Comment: @GregS darn, completely overlooked that second line

Comment: @userSeven7s why would you want to use that kind of implementation, with the `println` statements still in, while there is a proven `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding") available in case you want to perform per block encryption/decryption?

Comment: @userSeven7s AES is the standardized form of Rijndael. The only difference is that the block size has been set to 128, the available key sizes are 128, 192 or 256 bits and that specific number of rounds and constants are used for each key size. No need to go and look up Rijndael implementations (especially since the one you are using seems to only implement AES anyway).

Comment: @owlstead I changed my code to use in-built java package. Encrypting and decrypting works but some problem with padded plaintext. output:"Test������������������������" ??

Comment: @userSeven7s That looks OK, Java strings are not null-terminated, so what you are seeing is just the plain string with a lot of `\0` characters behind it. Java string decoding silently replaces them with a replacement string: `�`.

Comment: Yes. Understood that after I posted that comment. I stripped the null chars to fix the issue. Im using "NoPadding" so I should be taking care of padding the unpadding the plaintext.

Comment: So I guess that means problem solved?

Comment: @owlstead Yes.. will post a minimal solution soon..

Answer (score 2):

AES has a block size of 128 bits (i.e 16 bytes). It can *only* process data in blocks of this size, so even though you have told it to use `NoPadding` it is unable to comply.

The most likely thing that is happening here is that the AES implementation you are using is internally padding your four bytes of input up to 16 bytes and encrypting the result. When you decrypt, you get the same 16 bytes back out, i.e. 'T', 'e', 's', 't' and 12 garbage bytes.

The output you see supports this: "Test" followed by 24 `?` symbols. I don't know why it's printing two `?` symbols for each garbage byte, but I'm guessing it's something to do with interpreting the garbage bytes in unicode. You could see what is going on by printing out the raw byte values of the decrypted blob.

The short answer is that 'NoPadding' doesn't make sense for a block cipher (or, rather, if you are going to use NoPadding then you have to pad and unpad things yourself).

Comment: I guess, No padding indicates that the developer will take care of padding. I pad the data with null('\0') chars. while decrypting its my responsibility to remove the extra custom paddings. I fixed this by identifying the first index of null char and returning the preceding substring as plaintext.

Comment: My app has to work along side a legacy app so I cannot use other in-built padding options. the C++ legacy app uses '\0' for padding.